# logs are not getting pushed to elasticsearch from logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

logstash-config.conf

```
input {
 file {
path => ["D:/project/log/samplex.log"]
sincedb_path => "D:/Project/logstash-7.5.0/data/plugins/inputs/file/null"
start_position => "beginning"
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["192.168.1.8:9200"]
index => "db"
#user => "elastic"
#password => "changeme"
 }  }
```

Console log

> D:\Project\logstash-7.5.0\bin>logstash -f logstash-sample.conf
>   Thread.exclusive is deprecated, use Thread::Mutex   Sending Logstash
>   logs to D:/Project/logstash-7.5.0/logs which is now configured via
>   log4j2.properties   [2019-12-16T23:26:28,465][WARN
>   ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file
>   because modules or command line options are specified
>   [2019-12-16T23:26:28,580][INFO ][logstash.runner ] Starting Logstash
>   {"logstash.version"=>"7.5.0"} [2019-12-16T23:26:30,143][INFO
>   ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 32 ms to scan 1 urls,
>   producing 20 keys and 40 values [2019-12-16T23:26:31,024][INFO
>   ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs
>   updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://192.168.1.8:9200/]}}
>   [2019-12-16T23:26:31,201][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main]
>   Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://192.168.1.8:9200/"}
>   [2019-12-16T23:26:31,256][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main]
>   ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
>   [2019-12-16T23:26:31,264][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main]
>   Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used
>   to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
>   [2019-12-16T23:26:31,333][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main]
>   New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch",
>   :hosts=>["//192.168.1.8:9200"]} [2019-12-16T23:26:31,404][INFO
>   ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using default mapping template
>   [2019-12-16T23:26:31,439][WARN
>   ][org.logstash.instrument.metrics.gauge.LazyDelegatingGauge][main] A
>   gauge metric of an unknown type
>   (org.jruby.specialized.RubyArrayOneObject) has been create for key:
>   cluster_uuids. This may result in invalid serialization.  It is
>   recommended to log an issue to the responsible developer/development
>   team. [2019-12-16T23:26:31,449][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline
>   ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main",
>   "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125,
>   "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1000,
>   "pipeline.sources"=>["D:/Project/logstash-7.5.0/bin/logstash-sample.conf"],
>   :thread=>"#"} [2019-12-16T23:26:31,506][INFO
>   ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempting to install template
>   {:manage_template=>{"index_patterns"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001,
>   "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s", "number_of_shards"=>1},
>   "mappings"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message",
>   "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text",
>   "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*",
>   "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text",
>   "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword",
>   "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}],
>   "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"},
>   "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true,
>   "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"},
>   "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"},
>   "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}
>   [2019-12-16T23:26:32,041][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main]
>   Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
>   [2019-12-16T23:26:32,114][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ][main]
>   START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
>   [2019-12-16T23:26:32,118][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines
>   running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main],
>   :non_running_pipelines=>[]} [2019-12-16T23:26:32,502][INFO
>   ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API
>   endpoint {:port=>9600}

**The logstash doesnt read the log file mentioned and its in idle state.**

***samplex.log***

> [2019-12-16T22:30:59,310][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main]
>   Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[],
>   :added=>[http://192.168.1.8:9200/]}} [2019-12-16T22:30:59,472][WARN
>   ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES
>   instance {:url=>"http://192.168.1.8:9200/"}
>   [2019-12-16T22:30:59,558][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main]
>   ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
>   [2019-12-16T22:30:59,565][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main]
>   Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used
>   to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
>   [2019-12-16T22:30:59,653][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main]
>   New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch",
>   :hosts=>["//192.168.1.8:9200"]} [2019-12-16T22:30:59,724][INFO
>   ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using default mapping template
>   dsdasd

Comment: can you also post some sample data from that file?

Comment: Added the sample log file data @JBone.

Comment: Can you just try to add empty filter section to logstash-config.conf file, and try again.
And you can also add `stdout { codec => rubydebug}` inside of `output` section just to make sure that documents are processed from the file.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows,i think the file name you have saved is sample.log but internally it would be considered as text file . So it would be something like "sample.log.txt"

So please do try

```
input {
file {
#type => "log"
path => "D:/Downloads/logstash-6.7.0/bin/samplex.log.txt"
sincedb_path => "D:/Downloads/logstash-6.7.0/data/plugins/inputs/file/null"
start_position => "beginning"
#ignore_older => 0
}
}



output {
stdout { codec => "rubydebug"}
elasticsearch {
hosts => "http://xx-xx-xx-xx:9200"
index => "db"
} 
}
```

If still the issue is seen, try deleting the null file in sincedb_path and try again.

Please let me know,if issue is getting resolved with this.
Hope this helps you.. !!

Comment: I saved it as log file and my extension is in .log

Comment: Please access the file via cmd prompt, execute "dir" command to check the file extensions. If possible , paste the screenshot here. we can investigate further.